# synchronous messages from service to UI layer

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

is the order of a broadcast intent guaranteed? that is, if i do,

```
sendBroadcast(intent1);
sendBroadcast(intent2);
```

are the receivers guaranteed to get intent1 before intent2? i suspect the answer to this is no, but in that case, i'm not quite sure how to solve my problem.

i'm trying to create a "busy" indicator for my app that shows busy when the device is talking on the network, and then goes away when the network communication is done. all network communication happens in an intent service.

my attempt at this was to send a BUSY_START intent when i begin network communication in the service, and a BUSY_STOP when network communication ends. this seems to mostly work, but i'm finding occasionally that i get the stop and start messages out of order.

is there a better way to solve this problem?

i'm thinking of adding an ID to each busy intent, so they can be paired. that way if i receive a start for which i've already received a stop, i can ignore it. or, perhaps more simply, add an integer sequence number into each broadcast. if i ever receive a broadcast for which the sequence of the current intent is less than the sequence of the last received intent, ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one viable alternative to intents is to execute messaging through the application class, i.e.,

1. create a listener interface
2. Manager a collection of listener objects in the application / provide methods to add / remove listener
3. Interested entities call the application methods to add / remove themselves as listeners
4. Add "notify" methods in the application, that call the appropriate listener interface method on each of the registered listeners
5. Services call the application's notification methods to

For example,

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public interface MyListener {
    void onEvent();
  }

  private Set<MyListener> listeners = new HashSet<Listener>();

  public void addListener(MyListener l) {
    listeners.add(l);
  }

  public void removeListener(MyListener l) {
    listeners.remove(l);
  }

  public void sendEvent() {
    for (MyListener l: listeners) { l.onEvent(); }
  }
}
```

Now, from your activity (or fragment),

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyListener {
    ...
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public void onEvent() {
      // do something
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).addListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).removeListener(this);
    }
}
```

And in your service,

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).sendEvent();
```

This provides synchronous messaging without using intents or static variables.

Comment: This code, as you've presented it here, looks like it calls from the Service's thread directly into the main UI thread of the Activity.  That's a no-no.  I really think you need a Handler object if you want to call from one thread to another.

Comment: you are right, it does. assumption is that if the activity modifies the UI thread in `onEvent()` it should do it using `runOnUIThread()`. the callback framework could hide that if we wanted, but i'd rather leave it up to the UI thread to decide if it needs that extra step.

Comment: It's a good thing you mentioned that, for anyone who was looking to use your code example in their own app.

Comment: i'm not here to point out every nuance of android application development to folks. understanding that you can't update the UI hierarchy from a non-UI thread is a very basic concept. i already took quite a bit of time to come back here and write out a long and detailed answer to my own question. you are welcome for that. if you have a problem with it, i recommend to you vote to delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a `Handler` object to communicate from the background thread in the `IntentService`?  The advantage of a Handler over the `BroadcastReciver` approach is that the Handler uses a message queue to sequence the Message objects.

(I'm assuming your Service is in the same process as the app's main thread).

Comment: i'm trying to communicate from an IntentService to the UI thread.

Comment: Yup.  A Handler should do just that.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: in that case, you need to construct the handler in the activity and give the service a reference to it. how do you do that?

Comment: Short answer is to store it in a static variable someplace.  You can check out Google's example code for in-app billing.  Their code is a little over-engineered, but basically their Service calls static methods on a helper object which ultimately holds a static reference to the Handler object.  Or if you don't like statics (I don't) you could store a reference to it in your app's Application object, and have the service retrieve it from there.  If the service gets a null handler, it skips the messaging.

Comment: i can't accept that using a static field is best practice for communicating messages between components, regardless of the fact that it came from google sample code.